# Conservation of stress energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, general-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

> I want to show $\nabla_m T_{mn}=0$.

For this I have
\begin{align}
\nabla _m T_{mn}&=\nabla_m({F_m}^aF_{na}-\frac{1}{4}g_{mn}F_{ab}F^{ab})\\
&=(\nabla_m{F_m}^a)F_{na}+{F_m}^a(\nabla_mF_{na})-\frac{1}{4}\nabla_m(g_{mn}F_{ab}F^{ab})
\end{align}

How do I use $\nabla_mF^{mn}=0$ and $\nabla_{[m}F_{na]}=0$ to show that this is zero?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\nabla_m T_{mn}$ is not well-formed according to abstract index notation this is potentially ill-posed, let me rewrite you as asking for $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0$. You also appear to be asking about a particular case related to electromagnetism, $$T^{\mu\nu}=g_{\alpha\beta}~F^{\mu\alpha}~F^{\nu\beta} - \frac14 g^{\mu\nu}~F_{\alpha\beta}~F^{\alpha\beta}.$$

I think what you are missing is that $\nabla$ is usually taken to be [metric-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_connection#Metric_compatibility) with $g.$ This allows you to commute the $\nabla$ with any $g$ and to sort of raise and lower indices ad-hoc. So for example the first term above decomposes into: $$(\nabla_\mu g_{\alpha\beta})~F^{\mu\alpha}~F^{\nu\beta}+g_{\alpha\beta}~(\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\alpha})~F^{\nu\beta}+g_{\alpha\beta}~F^{\mu\alpha}~\nabla_\mu F^{\nu\beta}.$$Metric compatibility kills the first term, your first relation $\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = J^\nu = 0$ kills the second term in free space, so all that's left is the third term. Leave it for now.

Studying the second term we can immediately see that both our derivatives are going to be formally identical and we have an expression that we can immediately apply your identity to, $$-\frac12 g^{\mu\nu}~F^{\alpha\beta}~\nabla_\mu F_{\alpha\beta}=-\frac12 g^{\mu\nu}~F^{\alpha\beta}(\nabla_\alpha F_{\mu\beta} - \nabla_\beta F_{\mu\alpha}).$$With a bit more work writing e.g. $\nabla_\alpha F_{\mu\beta} = g_{\mu\kappa}~g_{\beta\lambda}~\nabla_\alpha F^{\kappa\lambda}$ and then relabeling some indices, we can discover that actually these two seemingly different terms are not only the same term, but that they are each negative-one-half of the third term above, so they all cancel leaving just $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = F^{\nu\beta} J_\beta = 0$ in free space.